# WooCommerce Display Digital Download Files Type and Size

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I sell digital downloads through WooCommerce. I'm looking to have it show the file size and file extension in the product listing as well as the download page when they complete the order. Is this even possible? Is there a plugin for this? I have searched high and low but must not be doing the best job. All advice/direction is appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't give you an answer, but there's a very active forum here for people asking questions about WooCommerce directly to the people who write it - might be a good bet for finding the answer to this question: https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/woocommerce/

Comment: You may have to calculate this yourself as I don't know that any of this is stored in the database.  I imagine this could be done with either PHP or JS.  Here's a jQuery method to get file size: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37603457/2757809 and this can get you the file type: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3042370/2757809  (A lot of varied answers there.)